# Is there a way to use the line number (lineno) in makeidx?

Tags: imakeidx, lineno

Is it possible to use the numbers from the `lineno` package as the counter in `imakeidx`?   As the MWE below shows, I tried using `xpatch` to change the counter for the index to `thelinenumber`, but without success:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}



\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeindex
\makeatletter



  \makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@wrindex}{\thepage}{\thelinenumber}{}{}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\linenumbers


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dapibus 
facilisis magna, id sodales ante convallis vitae. In a porttitor nibh, 
eget vehicula dui\index{test}. Integer feugiat dui nec neque porttitor, non eleifend 
erat lobortis. Sed varius malesuada nisi, id vulputate ante commodo vitae. 
Nam non felis at ante mollis commodo eget porttitor ex. Donec in quam diam. 
Maecenas fringilla, turpis a egestas pulvinar, massa lacus molestie enim, 
vel vulputate lorem ante ac velit. Nam ex nulla, venenatis et tortor at, 
efficitur fringilla ante.



\clearpage  \printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use `\thelinenumber`, because this would refer to the line number as computed when the paragraph has already been split into lines.

With your patch, the number you get is 1, because `\thelinenumber` is expanded at the wrong time; but with `\noexpand\thelinenumber` you'd get 8, because that's the value when the paragraph is being processed (it has seven lines).

You need to use the `\linelabel` mechanism.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno,refcount}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lineindex}[1]{\linelabel{#1}\index{#1}}
\patchcmd{\@wrindex}{\thepage}{\getrefnumber{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dapibus 
facilisis magna, id sodales ante convallis vitae. In a porttitor nibh, 
eget vehicula dui\lineindex{dui}. Integer feugiat dui nec neque porttitor, non eleifend 
erat lobortis. Sed varius malesuada nisi, id vulputate ante commodo vitae. 
Nam non felis at ante mollis commodo eget porttitor ex. Donec in quam diam. 
Maecenas fringilla, turpis a egestas pulvinar, massa lacus molestie enim\lineindex{enim}, 
vel vulputate lorem ante ac velit. Nam ex nulla, venenatis et tortor at, 
efficitur fringilla ante.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This requires two runs, for it uses `\ref` (actually the expandable version `\getrefnumber`).

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! As a follow up, do you know how it would be possible to print the page number followed by a colon, then the line number? I tried using \thepage:\getrefnumber{#2}, but that broke it :(

Comment: @linenonono `makeindex` only accepts simple numeric entries (the numbers can be Arabic, Roman or alphabetic).